# gRPC library is installed but doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, google-cloud-firestore, grpc

I'm having a error with google Firestore PHP Api, when I try to connect to Firestore the server return me this error: `The requested client requires the gRPC extension. Please see https://cloud.google.com/php/grpc for installation instructions`. The error comes from  `vendor/google/cloud/Core/src/ClientTrait.php` because the function isGrpLoaded response with a false:

```
/**
 * Abstract the checking of the grpc extension for unit testing.
 *
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 * @return bool
 */
protected function isGrpcLoaded()
{
    return extension_loaded('grpc');
}
```

I already installed gRPC following this instructions from google https://cloud.google.com/php/grpc. I install PECL, install Composer, install the gRPC extension, add the grpc extension to php.ini file, install the Protobuf Runtime library and also add the protobuf extension to php.ini.

So in my composer I have this lines:

```
...
google/grpc-gcp                       0.1.3    gRPC GCP library for channel management
google/protobuf                       v3.6.1   proto library for PHP
grpc/grpc                             1.15.0   gRPC library for PHP
...
```

In my php.ini file I have this two new lines:

```
extension=protobuf.so
extension=grpc.so
```

The problem comes here, when I execute in my server terminal this line:

```
sudo php -r "echo extension_loaded('grpc') ? 'yes' : 'no';"
```

the server response me with a `yes`, everything seems fine.

But if I create an php file like this:

```
<?php
  echo extension_loaded('grpc') ? 'yes' : 'no';
?>
```

The response is `no`.

I'm using

```
Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS 
PHP 7.2.13
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the error. 
The error was I edited the php.ini whats appers in `Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini` but I needed to edit the php.ini in Apache too, this file: `/etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini`

Comment: if you are using wamp, make sure you add the extension=php_grpc.dll in both php.ini files as well: in \wamp64\bin\php\php7.2.10 and in wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.35\bin

Comment: In case someone needs this, I was having MAMP but I intentionally was using CLI. However, "php artisan serve" has to be restarted for the changes to INI to be reflected.

Comment: I have the same problem but I don't seem to have the /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini when I try php --ini. Any solutions?

Comment: In my case, `php --ini` was showing warning saying `grpc.so` wasn't loaded from a given path. So, I added a symlink in the path where it expects from where it actually was.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Nginx and PHP FPM is running then `php --ini` may be outputting the wrong path of your ini file. You should use `phpinfo()` to check for the exact path.

In my case, having referenced `php --ini`, I was incorrectly updating `/etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini` when the actual file was `/etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini`.

On updating the correct file and restarting FPM with `systemctl restart php7.2-fpm.service` `phpinfo()` output a section on gRPC.

Comment: I was stuck and modifying ```/etc/php/8.1/fpm/php.ini``` + restarting fpm with this command unlocked everything, thank you !
(I also edited the same thing with apache just in case)
Be sure to check the php.ini files concerned if you are stuck.