# Extension gRPC loaded on server but extension_loaded('grpc') returns false when run in PHP

Tags: php, apache, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to use [Firestore PHP](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php-firestore) and Google Cloud requires gRPC. I have had it installed properly on the system.

To check, I run the following command from the CLI:

```
sudo php -r "echo extension_loaded('grpc') ? 'Yes' : 'No';"
```

It returns "Yes," indicating that GRPC is loaded.

However, I copy the same code an put it inside `index.php` file:

```
<?php

    echo extension_loaded('grpc') ? 'Yes' : 'No';

?>
```

And run the file, it returns "No."

I have made sure that all the php.ini on the server, as well as php.ini on the root folder of my web folder have the following:

```
extension = grpc.so
extension = protobuf.so
```

I can't figure out what when wrong. What should I do to have the `index.php` load the gRPC required for Google Cloud PHP?

Comment: Have you checked both the php.ini of your CLI and your webserver? Have you checked whether that additional php.ini in your "web folder" is loaded after all? Have you restarted your webserver after changing the configuration? And, after all, why is this question tagged with `composer-php` while this looks completely unrelated to me?

Comment: Could you confirm that you have followed all the steps of installing gRPC for PHP ? - https://cloud.google.com/php/grpc . Moreover, where are you trying to run the code? ( App Engine flex, Cloud Run etc.. )

Comment: @NicoHaase: Yes. I even went an extra step and search for all php.ini in the server and add the extension to ALL of them. None works.

Comment: @AndreiTigau: I have followed the instruction given. I am trying to run it on my VPS, Centos 7.

Comment: I am not sure how your application structure is, but, probably you should have a php.ini in the apache sub-folder, as well. Have you added the proper extensions in that file, as well? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53859867/grpc-library-is-installed-but-doesnt-work

Comment: Did you resolve this issue, i am stuck on this issue

Answer (score 1):

Is solved bby restarting fpm service too